# need a Jquery slider like this

Tags: jquery

I am looking for a jquery image slider like this. 
[image]

any help is appreciated.

Thanks.

Comment: [Google shows a lot](http://googleitfor.me/?q=jQuery+horizontal+image+slider+plugin)

Answer (score 0):

Try [jCarouselLite](http://www.gmarwaha.com/jquery/jcarousellite/) out, it allows you to have a scrollable image-based slider and also repeats/cycles through items so you never feel like you reach the end of your content. Infinite scrolling. It's easy to use and has saved me a lot of time on projects.

This is also now hosted on [github](https://github.com/orangewise/jcarousellite) so if there's something that it doesn't do check out the forks and see if they might help get you where you need to be.